# JS Media Query is not working on svg element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG element that I am trying to media query in JS. Somehow the query is not working because the changes in style is seen in all sizes of the browser. I am using JS query instead of css because css does not let me grab the "dx" svg attribute. Much help needed. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<text id="textnew" transform-orgin="center" onclick="grow()" dx="40%" dy="80%" fill="white">This
                is my story.</text>
```

CSS

```
#textnew {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
function myFunction(x) {
      if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        var mobileText = document.getElementById("textnew")
        mobileText.setAttribute("dx", 120);
        mobileText.style.fill = "red";
      }
    }
    var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 5.5in)")
    myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
    x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added to your function an `else`. Also I've removed `onclick="grow()"` since there is no `grow()` in the javascript. The SVG element has a [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
      if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        var mobileText = document.getElementById("textnew")
        mobileText.setAttribute("dx", 120);
        mobileText.style.fill = "red";
      }else{
        textnew.style.fill = "white";
        textnew.setAttribute("dx", 48);
      }
    }
    var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 5.5in)")
    myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
    x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on s
```

```css
body{background:black}

svg{border:1px solid #333}

#textnew {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="40 0 370 40">
<text id="textnew" transform-orgin="center" dx="40%" dy="80%" fill="white">This
  is my story.</text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I found out my error. The code works find without "var mobileText = document.getElementById("textnew")" and somehow even though i set the element to var mobileText. The code only works when I use "textnew." instead. Do you know why this is?